# How to add conditional statements in reactJS map function

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to render different tags based JSON keys, but it keeps throwing syntax error...
adding only one of the two conditions works though !
How can I do it right ?

```
<ul className="features">
{
property.details.features.map((idx, feature) =>
feature.hasOwnProperty(area) ? 
<li>
<span className="icon-frame"/>
<div className="english">{feature[area]}m2 </div>
</li> : null
feature.hasOwnProperty(bedRoom) ? <li>
<span className="fa fa-bed"/>
<div className="english">{feature[bedRoom]}</div>
</li> :null

)
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have an arrow function without braces in the body of the function, which means the expression right after the arrow will be what that function returns. But you have two expressions in a row there (the two ternary operators), so it won't know what to return, hence the syntax error. You can try this:

```
<ul className="features">
  {
    property.details.features.map((idx, feature) =>
      feature.hasOwnProperty(area) ? 
        (
          <li>
            <span className="icon-frame"/>
            <div className="english">{feature[area]}m2 </div>
          </li>
        ) 
      : feature.hasOwnProperty(bedRoom) ? 
        (
          <li>
            <span className="fa fa-bed"/>
            <div className="english">{feature[bedRoom]}</div>
          </li>
        ) 
     : null
    )
  }
</ul>
```

So, if feature has the attribute area, then render the first, else, if it has the attribute bedrom, then render the second, else, return null. I tried to make it as readable as possible but it's never easy with long ternary operators.
You can always just wrap the body of the arrow function and do it with `if`, `else` and `return` statements.